# How to know if a variable is in an attribute of an object in a list?

Tags: python, list, object, attributes

To check if a variable is in a list, I know that one can use `if variable in list`. In my instance, I have a list of objects, all of which have the attribute "id", I want to check if an object in a list has a specific ID, but I'm not sure how I would go about doing that.

I already tried looking this up on google as well as here but I couldn't find any relevant results. That might be because I don't really know how to phrase my question correctly, so if my question doesn't make sense let me know and I'll try to explain it better.

Comment: So, you have a list of objects and **each** of them has the attribute `id` --- and you just want to check whether there exists some object `o` for which the value of it's attribute `id` is equal to some specific id. Did I get you right?

Comment: Yes, you got it right, that is exactly what I want to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to get a list of all ids and the check if your `id` is `in` that list:

```
if my_id in [o.id for o in my_list]:
    do_something()
```

Or you can use the [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#any) method like this:

```
if any(my_id == o.id for o in my_list):
    do_something()
```

Answer (score 1):

So if you want only to check if there is any item in the list that has a specific attribute you can do this:

```
if any(hasattr(i, str(variable)) for i in your_list):
  do_something()
```

And if you want to get the all items that contains this attribute you can do something like that:

```
contain_attribute = [i for i in x if hasattr(i, variable)]
```

And for your question, just to make sure all your items has the attribute `id` and avoid `AttributeError`:

```
if variable in [i.id for i in x if hasattr(i, "id")]:
    do_something
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, in my specific instance I don't need to check if an object has an attribute, but I think it would be good practice in the future for me to do so, so thank you for showing me how to in advance!

Answer (score 0):

it is a way to search an specific object inside a list of same objects. I  know you are using python, i dont know python but i wrote it in other code. hope it helps.

> In my instance, I have a list of objects, all of which have the
>   attribute "id"

List and Object.getId()

I want to check if an object in a list has a specific ID, but I'm not sure how I would go about doing that.

```
int mySpecificID = 3;
List<MyObject> list;
for(MyObject myobject : list)
{
   if(myobject.getId()==mySpecificID)
   {
     //We found it
     MyObject objectFound = myobject;
   }
}
```

Or

```
int mySpecificID = 3;
List<MyObject> list;      
for(int i = 0; i < list.count(); i++)
{
  if(list[i].Id==mySpecificId)
  {
   //We found it again
   MyObject objectFound = list[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: The tag python suggests the language he's using.

Comment: yeah im new in the site, i just saw it hehe